# Insert comma between a specific words in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, insert, between

I find lines from a document that contain ' Bon État' with:

```
if ' Bon État' in i:
   print (i)
```

res:

```
0,FENÊTRES Bon État,Présence d’une sérigraphie sur les vitrages,
5,VOLETS / STORES Bon État,,
```

I want to put a commas just before ' Bon État' like that:

```
0,FENÊTRES ,Bon État,Présence d’une sérigraphie sur les vitrages,
5,VOLETS / STORES ,Bon État,,
```

moreover I would like to be able to apply this to something other than ' Bon État'.

Comment: perhaps `yourstring.replace("Bon État", ",Bon État")`?

Comment: Yep I tried but I was doing it wrong. Thank's!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to do the following program :

```
s = "ok Bon État super"
s = s.replace("Bon État",",Bon État")
```